# "PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already" error in integration tests with jOOQ & Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

There are already similar questions about this error and suggested solutions; e.g. increasing `max_connections` in `postgresql.conf` and / or adapting the max number of connections your app requests. However, my question is more specific to using jOOQ in a Spring Boot application.

I integrated jOOQ into my application as in the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example). Namely, I am using `DataSourceConnectionProvider` with `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` to handle database connections, and I inject the `DSLContext` in the classes that need it.

My application provides various web services to front-ends and I've never encountered that PSQLException on dev or test environments so far. I only started getting that error when running all integration tests (around 1000) locally. I don't expect some leak in handling the connection as Spring and jOOQ manage the resources; nevertheless that error got me worried if that would also happen on production.

**Long story short, is there a better alternative to using `DataSourceConnectionProvider` to manage connections?** Note that I already tried using `DefaultConnectionProvider` as well, and tried to make `spring.datasource.max-active` less than `max_connections` allowed by Postgres. Neither fixed my problem so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question seems not to be about the generally best way to work with PostgreSQL connections / data sources, I'll answer the part about jOOQ and using its [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html):

#### Using `DataSourceConnectionProvider`

There is no *better alternative* in general. In order to understand `DataSourceConnectionProvider` (the implementation), you have to understand [`ConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html) (its specification). It is an SPI that jOOQ uses for two things:

- to [`acquire()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#acquire--) a connection prior to running a statement or a transaction
- to [`release()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#release-java.sql.Connection-) a connection after running a statement (and possibly, fetching results) or a transaction

The `DataSourceConnectionProvider` does so by acquiring a connection from your `DataSource` through [`DataSource.getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()) and by releasing it through [`Connection.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--). This is the most common way to interact with data sources, in order to let the `DataSource` implementation handle transaction and/or pooling semantics.

Whether this is a good idea *in your case* may depend on individual configurations that you have made. It generally is a good idea because you usually don't want to manually manage connection lifecycles.

#### Using `DefaultConnectionProvider`

This can certainly be done instead, in case of which jOOQ does not [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) your connection for you, you'll do that yourself. I'm expecting this to have no effect in your particular case, as you'll implement the `DataSourceConnectionProvider` semantics manually using e.g.

```java
try (Connection c = ds.getConnection()) {

    // Implicitly using a DefaultConnectionProvider
    DSL.using(c).select(...).fetch();

// Implicit call to c.close()
}
```

In other words: this is likely not a problem related to jOOQ, but to your data source.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for the answer. `DataSourceConnectionProvider`  seems to provide the desired behavior for me, I will stick to that. So far I've been using the default data source created by Spring with default values such as max 100 idle & active connections. I will adapt the configuration for integration tests then; no code changes sound necessary to me based on your reply.